# Python foor loop adding random date in list

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a 3 list, that print equally based on date after date,
for example:
xlist
ylist
xlist
xlist
ylist etc.....

here is my current script:

```
import datetime as dt
import pandas as pd

start_date = dt.datetime(2019, 4,12)
end_date = dt.datetime(2019, 4,21)
daterange = pd.date_range(start_date, end_date)

XLIST = ['401', 'Pabolo Picasso', '402', 'Justin TED', '303', 'Ariana Great']
YLIST = ['201', 'Donald Ted', '202', 'Einastain', '203', 'Hillary Cloud']
ZLIST = ['301', 'Theresa March', '302', 'Jullian Ass Bad', '303', 'Messi Bro']

i = 0
for date in daterange:
    if i % 3 == 0:
        print(XLIST)
    elif i % 3 == 1:
        print(YLIST)
    else:
        print(ZLIST)
    i+=1
```

Above script output is:

```
['401', 'Pabolo Picasso', '402', 'Justin TED', '303', 'Ariana Great']
['201', 'Donald Ted', '202', 'Einastain', '203', 'Hillary Cloud']
['301', 'Theresa March', '302', 'Jullian Ass Bad', '303', 'Messi Bro']
['401', 'Pabolo Picasso', '402', 'Justin TED', '303', 'Ariana Great']
['201', 'Donald Ted', '202', 'Einastain', '203', 'Hillary Cloud']
['301', 'Theresa March', '302', 'Jullian Ass Bad', '303', 'Messi Bro']
['401', 'Pabolo Picasso', '402', 'Justin TED', '303', 'Ariana Great']
['201', 'Donald Ted', '202', 'Einastain', '203', 'Hillary Cloud']
['301', 'Theresa March', '302', 'Jullian Ass Bad', '303', 'Messi Bro']
['401', 'Pabolo Picasso', '402', 'Justin TED', '303', 'Ariana Great']
```

and the output doesn't satisfy me:

**I need the date should be in list too:**

Here is my expected output:

```
[12/04/2019, '401', 'Pabolo Picasso', '402', 'Justin TED', '303', 'Ariana Great']
[13/04/2019, '201', 'Donald Ted', '202', 'Einastain', '203', 'Hillary Cloud']
[14/04/2019, '301', 'Theresa March', '302', 'Jullian Ass Bad', '303', 'Messi Bro']
[15,04/2019,'401', 'Pabolo Picasso', '402', 'Justin TED', '303', 'Ariana Great']
[16/04/2019, '201', 'Donald Ted', '202', 'Einastain', '203', 'Hillary Cloud']
[17/04/2019, '301', 'Theresa March', '302', 'Jullian Ass Bad', '303', 'Messi Bro']
[18/04/2019, '401', 'Pabolo Picasso', '402', 'Justin TED', '303', 'Ariana Great']
[19/04/2019, '201', 'Donald Ted', '202', 'Einastain', '203', 'Hillary Cloud']
[20/04/2019, '301', 'Theresa March', '302', 'Jullian Ass Bad', '303', 'Messi Bro']
[21/04/2019, '401', 'Pabolo Picasso', '402', 'Justin TED', '303', 'Ariana Great']
```

**Guide: If you see the script and expected output, then you will not what i am looking and where I have stopped.
much appreciated**

Answer (score 0):

Create a new list in the loop so the originals are not modified:

```
for date in daterange:
    if i % 3 == 0:
        print([str(date)] + XLIST)
    elif i % 3 == 1:
        print([str(date)] + YLIST)
    else:
        print([str(date)] + ZLIST)
    i+=1
```

You will probably want to format the date instead of just calling `str`.
Anyway, here you have the [live example](https://repl.it/repls/YellowishWelltodoTags)